# Storing assets like css, js, images automatically to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an ecommerce web app which constantly gets updated with modified css, js and new images that are being part of visuals like banners images, icons, promotion images etc. At present all of these assets are part of build which gets deployed on server.

Due to constant addition of these assets, now my build has reached to size of approx 200 MB, in which around 150 MB is taken up by these assets. I am looking for an approach by which these assets reside on S3 and not in project. But manually uploading each asset is an unmanageable task and that too when you are doing development and not sure whether that asset will be part of production version or not.

I am looking for some suggestion or pointers to help me solve this problem.

Comment: How do you build and deploy? Automation or creating a pipeline takes some effort, but sounds like it should pay off in the long run. Jenkins might work for you. Uploading to S3 with version numbers in the static resources would be important, that way you can still set caching headers. Might be worth using CloudFront as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@Abhi](https://serverfault.com/users/131820/abhi), today 200 MB on a development machine is not too much to decide to host the files only externally (on S3 for example). Especially if you need to test your application regularly with those assets on development machines.

So, if you can do it I advise you to store your files both in your project and on an Amazon S3 bucket. Also, the files stored on your project should be versioned (with GIT for example).

You can update your builds to change the application package by removing the assets from it. Then change URL generation in your app to make the URLs point to the files on S3.

If the majority of your files are not modified and you only add / delete / update few files regularly you can upload only diffs through your builds. (i.e do not re-upload everything, do not re-upload files which do not change).

If think about 3 different tools and solutions to do this.

**First solution, with the AWS CLI**

The [S3 `sync` CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). With this command you have few interesting options depending on your needs.

- The `--size-only` option will force to consider a file to be updated only if its size changes (i.e the last modified date of your file will be ignored) ;
- The `--delete` option is useful to cleanup deleted files on S3.

**WARNING** : Their are cases where you could have files with same sizes but different contents. For example if you file contains `AAAA` and then is changed to `BBBB`. In this case the S3 `sync` command will not consider your file as updated.

**Second solution, with s3cmd**

If the first solution do not work with your use case because of the previously mentioned warning you can use a tool which syncs based on file hashes, I would advise [s3-cmd-sync](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync) for this.

**Third solution, with mounts**

You could also use [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse), I personally do not like this solution because.

- You would have to ask all your developers to configure the mounts correctly ;
- If your are using Windows you would have to use an other tool like [TntDrive](https://tntdrive.com/) ;
- Amazon S3 *is not a filesystem* but more something like a "NoSQL key-value database".

**Final notes**

- As [@Tim](https://serverfault.com/users/306795/tim) advised it would be a good idea to trigger your builds and synchronizations from a CI server. If your project and assets are store in a GIT repository you should base your syncs from the master branch in your CI builds.
- Using Amazon S3 is a good idea for performances, durability and costs. You would improve your setup even more by configuring a CloudFront distribution in Front of your Amazon S3 bucket. Access to your files would be faster and you could save much more money.